# Detect specific characters in pandas dataframe

Tags: python

How to detect columns and rows that might have one of the characters in a string of a dataframe element other than the desired characters.

desired characters are A, B, C, a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, &, %, =, /

dataframe -

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Abc | Øa | 12 |
| bbb | + | } |

output will be elements Øa, +, } and their location in dataframe.

Comment: You can use contains() in Python with regex.

Comment: Hello Data007. What specifically is it that you want? Do you want to loop through all the columns? What would you like the result to be? What have you tried? Are you getting any errors, or unexpected results?

Comment: Hi @KarlWilhelm, I have reframed the question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I find it really difficult to locate an element for a condition directly in pandas, so I converted the dataframe to a nested list first, then proceeded to work with the list. Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#creating your sample dataframe
array = np.array([['Abc','Øa','12'],['bbb','+','}']]) 
columns = ['Col1','Col2','Col3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data=array, columns=columns)

#convert dataframe to nested list
pd_list = df.values.tolist() 

#return any characters other than the ones in 'var'
all_chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~Ø'
var = 'ABCabc123&%=//' 
for a in var:
    all_chars = all_chars.replace(a, "")

#stores previously detected elements to prevent duplicate
temp_storage = []

#loops through the nested list to get the elements' indexes
for x in all_chars:
    for i in pd_list:
        for n in i:
            if x in n:
                #check if element is duplicate
                if not n in temp_storage: 
                    temp_storage.append(n)
                    print(f'found {n}: row={pd_list.index(i)}; col={i.index(n)}')
```

Output:

```
> found +: row=1; col=1     
> found }: row=1; col=2
> found Øa: row=0; col=1
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I have reframed my question to what I am looking for.

Comment: @Data007 I have included 'Ø' in all_chars, new output is correct.

Comment: @Data007 Are you able to solve the problem?

Comment: Andrew, your code works but is there a way to scale your  solution if more data gets added over period of time with new unwanted characters?